# What is the font size height in points in a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, typography

I know that titles in toolbars use font HelveticaNeue-Medium and other fonts there are HelveticaNeue-Light but what is the font size (the default Apple uses)?

Is it 14.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/  you will get iOS default fonts.